# How to specify unique together index in gorm?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

```
type ABC struct {
ID uint
 Abc int `gorm:"unidqueIndex;
Bcd string
}
```

I want Field `Abc` and `Bcd` to be unique together

`{Abc: 1, Bcd: "hello"} {Abc: 1, Bcd: "hi"}` should be valid but

`{Abc: 1, Bcd: "hello"} {Abc: 1, Bcd: "hello"}` should be invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give both fields the same index name.

```
type ABC struct {
 ID uint
 Abc int `gorm:"uniqueIndex:abc_bcd_uniq"`
 Bcd string `gorm:"uniqueIndex:abc_bcd_uniq"`
}
```

See [composite indexes in the GORM docs](https://gorm.io/docs/indexes.html#Composite-Indexes).